# How do I parse a PHP serialized datastructure in Java?

Tags: java, php, serialization

I have a system that combines the best and worst of Java and PHP. I am trying to migrate a component that was once written in PHP into a Java One.

Does anyone have some tips for how I can parse a PHP serialized datastructure in Java? By serialized I mean output from php's serialize function.

Comment: Alternatively you could modify the PHP to let is serialize to a cross-platform format like JSON, or XML if you want to be fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP serializes to a simple text-based format. [PHPSerialize](http://hurring.com/scott/code/java/serialize/v0.1/PHPSerialize.java) looks like a parser written in Java. You can also port the [Python implementation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/phpserialize/1.1) to Java -- I doubt it's very complex.

Comment: Perfect a library.  You're right it's not complex, just didn't want to reinvent the wheel if I didn't have to.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found this library:
http://code.google.com/p/serialized-php-parser/

It does exactly what you need