# PHP compatible serialization from C/C++

Tags: php

Anyone know of a library that allows data to be serialized in C++ such that it can be deserialized using the default PHP 'unserialize' function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several implementations for other languages here

http://objectmix.com/php/362009-specification-serialize.html#post1335166

The C implementation used by PHP itself is also here:

http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_2/ext/standard/var.c

http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_2/ext/standard/var_unserializer.c

However, unless you're absolutely certain that your choice serialization format is going to be a major bottleneck, consider using a more readily available serialization format, like JSON, XML, Protocol Buffers, or WDDX.

Comment: Both links of svn.php.net is not accessible.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're probably only serializing data, and not PHP objects, you may find a standardized "common ground" serialization more effective. (JSON is likely the simplest)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [same question for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98090/how-do-i-parse-a-php-serialized-datastructure-in-java).  It should be pretty easy to write your own with examples.  PHP its self is written in c and you could modify the deserialize [source](http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/var_unserializer.c) to your needs.