# Why do it is required to type cast a pointer?

Tags: c, sockets

Hi to C programming expert

I am not an expert in C. I am trying to find answer for [php passing c struct data throught socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993762/php-passing-c-struct-data-throught-socket-programming/3996282#3996282)

Therefore I am starting a new thread to ask specifically on C language

below is the data:

```
typedef struct
{
  UI2             todo;   
  char            rz[LNG_RZ + 1]; 
  char            saId[LNG_SAT_ID + 1]; 
  char            user[LNG_USER + 1]; 
  char            lang[LANGLEN + 1]; 
  SI4             result;       
  UI4             socket;  
  char            text[LNG_ALLG + 1]; 
  char            filename[MAX_PATHLEN];
}  dmsAuf_Head;
```

And this data is required to be send through socket via this:

```
rval = send(dms_aufHead->socket, (char *) dms_aufHead, sizeof(dmsAuf_Head), 0);
```

Why is it required to **type cast** the data via

> (char *) dms_aufHead

before sending through socket?

Could you guys guess? Do you mind explaining in abit layman term. Thank you.

Comment: welcome to SO. Please could you rephrase the title of your question such that it is grammatically correct and makes sense in itself, please?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is a typo or not, but you don't need to cast to `char*`, but you forgot to take the address of your variable with the `&` operator. Then `send` takes a `void const*` pointer for the buffer, so all should be fine. This should do it:

```
rval = send(dms_aufHead->socket, &dms_aufHead, sizeof(dmsAuf_Head), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The send function requires a `char *` argument. That is the only reason. The types you pass to a function have to be correct.

Comment: The type for the buffer pointer parameter was changed to `void *` many years ago.

Comment: @jilles: Oh, dear. Now I feel quite the fool. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to cast the pointer. `send` takes a `const void *` argument, and simply taking the address of your structure will automatically convert to a `void *`.