# Trying to figure out what {s: ;} tags mean and where they come from

Tags: tags, rightnow-crm

I am working on migrating posts from the RightNow infrastructure to another service called ZenDesk.  I noticed that whenever users added files or even URL links, when I pull the xml data from RightNow it gives me a lot of weird codes like this:

`{s:3:""url"";s:45:""/files/56f5be6c1/MUG_presso.pdf"";s:4:""name"";s:27:""MUG presso.pdf"";s:4:""size"";s:5:""2.1MB"";}`

It wasn't too hard to write something that parses them and makes normal urls and links, but I was just wondering if this is something specific to the RightNow service, or if it is a tag system that is used.  I tried googling for this but am getting some weird results so, thought stack overflow might have someone who has run into this one.

So, anyone know what these {s ;} tags are called and if there are any particular tools to use to read them?

Any answers appreciated!

Comment: this looks like serialized data. what language are you working in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resembles partial PHP serialized data, as returned by the `serialize()` call. It looks like someone may have turned each `"` into `""`, which could prevent it from parsing properly. If it's wrapped with text like this before the `{s:` section, it's almost definitely PHP.

`a:6:{i:1;a:10:{s:`

These letters/numbers mean things like "an array with six elements follows", "a string of length 20 follows", etc.

You can use any PHP instance with [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to handle the data. If those double-quotes are indeed returned by the API, you might need to replace `:""` and `"";` with `"` before parsing.

Parsing modules exist for other languages like [Python](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). You can find more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197478/293352).